# C# Product Calculation Tool

Tags: c#

I am looking to implement a product calculation tool into my web site and I am looking for advise on possible tutorials/web links people may have to help with this. The tool will be used for a joinery website. What I am wanting the form to do is add values from different drop down lists and produce a quote price.

The form would have several drop down lists for example: item, size, finish, wood type etc. Obviously each item would have different sizes, finishes etc so these would need to be dependant on what item the user selected. The user would be able to select different values for each drop down box and then they would hit a calculate button. this would then produce a quote for the dimensions etc that they have selected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Framework is .Net Framework 4

Comment: can you provide a bit more insight, do you have a particular framework in mind , WebForms or MVC ? or are you not sure, please edit and update

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: edited and updated as requested.

Comment: The question is for any help to possible start points through tutorial/web links work or if anyone has any advice in general

Answer (score 0):

Without further information a simple approach would be to create dropdowns which has the selected products price as value.

Then you can summarize the values of all selected dropdowns to get a quote price.

Have a look at [this example](http://jsbin.com/aqopec/5) I've made on jsbin.

UPDATE: [New example where size changes when you select "Chair" as product](http://jsbin.com/aqopec/18).

Comment: hi, what further information would you require? Happy to answer any questions. The link you provided is great as a starting point but would need something probably more advanced for example the second drop down box would be dependant on the value selected in the first box etc.

Comment: You'll have to implement some logic for linking the data together. For example you could ask the server for values to populate related dropdowns when another is changed?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the part about the form.
I've looked at your other questions you posted and found out you know how to use SQL. Now's the time to use it.
First you need to think of all the information you're program is going to require.

What i'd do from here is keep a database with tables containing whatever information you need about your products. `ID`, `Name`, `Color` , `Type`, `Price` etc.

The next step would be for you to develop the programs interface with your `ComboBoxe` in which I would change the `DropDownStyle` properties to `DropDownList` to prevent the user from typing in your boxes an item that is not in the database.

I don't know if you've worked with SQL connections before but it's pretty easy to learn.

```
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Server = (Local); Integrated Security = True;" + "Database = insertDataBaseName"); // Change the Database Name
        myConnection.Open();
```

This is the connection string you'll need considering your using  Local database.

You'll now require some `SqlCommands` to access your tables in your database.
Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) for `SqlCommands`.
Since you only want to read data from your tables I would consider using `SqlDataReader` since it's easier to use than a `DataAdapter` and `DataSet`. You can find information about the reader [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx).

Now once you've learned how to read data from your SQL database you'll need to fill your `ComboBox` like this

```
          while(myDataReader.Read())
          {
           myComboBox.Items.Add(myDataReader["insertColumnNameHere"].ToString());
          }
```

This will fill your box with items from your database and from the specified tables you requested in your `SqlCommand`.

Now that all your `ComboBoxes` are filled your ready for the calculate button.
Here you'll need the same type of connection, command and reader you've used previously but this time to check for the price of all the articles selected and store them in variables.

(eg. `myComboBox.SelectedItem`)

From here it'll be easy to calculate the rest.
If you need to go and change the value in the database (like if the article is has been sold) i'd look into stored procedure [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) because they can be called using a simple `DataReader`.

Hope this pointed you in the right direction.
Don't hesitate if you have any questions ans good luck.